# Implementing message and textarea/input layout in html separation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement something similar to slack's messages presentation, where the textarea is always at the bottom and the messages are always above the textarea

Using boostrap so this the html

```
<div id="chat" class="container top-padding">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="message-box">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                Message 1
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                Message 2
            </div>
        </div>

        ...
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control col-md-12" id="text-box"></textarea>
</div>
```

## css

```
.top-padding {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#chat .card {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#text-box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 88%;
}

#message-box {
    height: calc(100% - 18px);
}
```

## screenshot of results

[image]

This shows with `position absolute` on the textarea and bottom `10px` it will be at the bottom and as you scroll down it will start to move up. Also trying to use height as `calc(100% - 18px)` to `message-box` to limit the height on the div with the `card`s doesn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no `overflow` property to the `message-box` (which gives default **visible** property to it), scrolling down will result in scrolling of parent element, which is the `chat` element. This results in moving the `textarea` upwards.

The solution to your problem is simple, just add **overflow-y: auto** to `message-box` element.

**Update:** height also has to be changed from `(100% - 18px)` to `(100vh - 90px)`, note the change of `%` to `vh`. Have a look at the updated snippet below:

```css
<style>
.top-padding {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#chat .card {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#text-box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 88%;
}

#message-box {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chat" class="container top-padding">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="message-box">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 1
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 2
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 3
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 4
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 5
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 6
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 7
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 8
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 9
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 10
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 11
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Message 12
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control col-md-12" id="text-box"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, you get the inner scroll bar (without the scroll bar) and if you scroll you still scroll the entirety of the page so the textarea also moves up.

Comment: @SamuelM. sorry for that, just adding the overflow-y worked in my browser but when I cross checked it in stackoverflow's code snippet it doesn't work... The issue is with height of message-box. Changing the height to `(100vh-90px)` along with `overflow-y: auto` (auto is better than scroll in this case) will solve the problem. I have updated the answer, have a look at it :)